# GWT MVP Update the History-Token without changing the Activity

Tags: gwt, android-activity, history, mvp, gwt-history

my problem is the following: I have a MVP GWT application with a table in which datasets are shown. There are several hundreds of datasets and so I decided to split the table in pages of 20 results each. I load each page from the server via a GWT-RPC Service who gets the pagenumber as an argument.

Now I want to do the following: I want to save the page of the table the user sees in the History-Token (so the token would be something like TablePlace:page=5), but I do not want to create a new activity because then the state of the other elements (for example there is a TreeView) the activity manages would be lost. In my case all the items of the TreeView become closed, which is not what I want.

If I don't fire new Places the user can't use the browser's back button to get back to the page he visited before.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd issue a *normal* `PlaceController` `goTo` to navigate to another place, but in your `ActivityMapper`, you'd return the exact same `Activity` instance as before. In that specific case, the `ActivityManager` doesn't stop/start the activity, but instead let it run it's own life (without even signaling the place has changed; if you want that, then have your `ActivityMapper` tell your `Activity` before returning it).

You might also find the `FilteredActivityMapper` and `CachingActivityMapper` useful for returning the same activity for slightly different places, without placing the burden into your own mapper.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that did it. Here's what I've done:   in my getActivity(Place place) method of the AppActivityMapper I wrote the following: if (place instanceof AbstractPlace && ((AbstractPlace) place).isSelfFired()) { return lastActivity; }
AbstractPlace is a class I wrote already and therefore it was pretty easy to add the selfFired boolean. If my Activity creates a place to itself it sets this attribute to true, otherwise it's false.